# Cannot grab text between span tags

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am having a heck of a time grabbing text from the span tag (568,789,073,292). The text is constantly changing. See HTML below.

I thought this should work but its not

```
xpath=(//div[@id='RxValidPackets']/span)[3]
```

The elements below is from row 3 of a table.

When I try to grab row 6, I try this

```
xpath=(//div[@id='RxValidPackets']/span)[6]
```

There are 6 rows of data with the same elements. The only difference is the span tags.

Can you help?

Here is the HTML:

```
<td class="field-undefined-container">
    <div id="RxValidPackets" class="field-container-value">
        <span>568,789,073,292</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: *"I thought this should work but its not.."* And what is actual output?

Comment: Please read this page showing what you should include in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So how do I make the id's unique? – 
joe john
 yesterday   
I got the following error: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@id[1]='RxValidPackets']/span)[3] because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@id[1]='RxValidPackets']/span)[3]' is not a valid XPath expression. – 
joe john
 yesterday   
I did this command: elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id[1]='RxValidPackets']/span)[3]").click() –

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use the same ID in every row. In an HTML document, IDs are unique.

Comment: So how do I make the id's unique?

Comment: I got the following error:
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@id[1]='RxValidPackets']/span)[3] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@id[1]='RxValidPackets']/span)[3]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I did this command:

elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id[1]='RxValidPackets']/span)[3]").click()